# Function alnum is not displaying correct amount

Tags: c++

I want to display the amount of alphanumeric characters from a text file but each time I run the code it only shows 11 characters regardless of which text file I use.

```
// Loop to read from input file
cout << "Reading lines from file '" << INPUT_FILE_NAME
  << "' ..." << endl << endl;
lineCount = 0;
while (inFile.good())
{
  getline(inFile, line);
  
  lineCount = lineCount + 1;
}
 

// Close input file
inFile.close();
cout << endl << lineCount << " line(s) read from file '" 
  << INPUT_FILE_NAME << "'." << endl << endl;


 //count number of alphanumeric char
   
 alnum =0;
 while (isalnum(INPUT_FILE_NAME[alnum])) alnum++;
 printf ("Alphanumeric chars: %d \n",alnum);



 // Show application close
 cout << "End of Text Turtles" << endl;

}
```

Comment: You should explain this: `while (isalnum(INPUT_FILE_NAME[alnum])) alnum++;` to your favourite [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Why is there no bounds checking? Why does it stop after the first non-alnum-character? Why does it operate on the _file name_?

Comment: This is your loop: "As long as the `alnum`:th character of the file name is alphanumerical, increment `alnum`". Think about it until you see that it can't be right.

Comment: So just to clarify, what I've written so far runs to only print the name of the text file and not the actual text file?

Comment: Note that `while (inFile.good())` only says the stream is good at that exact point. `getline(inFile, line);` could subsequently fail and it will still be counted. You need to read, then test, then use. Example: `while (getline(inFile, line)) { lineCount = lineCount + 1; }`. This gets a line, and only enters the loop if a line was gotten.

Comment: @user14443749 Correct. Maybe you got a huge misconception we need to clear up. Why do you think the code would operate on the contents of the file? For the rest of the logic: Maybe write down an algorithm with pen and paper first, then translate it to C++.

Comment: I'm honestly just not sure what to use exactly to get the amount of alphanumerics from the text itself. Would I use an if/else statement?

Comment: That's the way, yes :) You read the file line by line, now you only need to check every character of every line if it's alnum or not. If it is, increase some counter.